# Golden ratio as a property of conic section (is it known?)

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, conic-sections

I am looking for a proof of a discovery as follows:

> *Let $ABC$ be arbitrary triangle and $(\Omega)$ be an arbitrary circumconic of $ABC$ let  $A'B'C'$ is its [tangential triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentialTriangle.html) of $ABC$ respect to $(\Omega)$. Let $BB'$ meet $AC$ at $D$ and $CC'$ meet $AB$ at $E$, let $DE$ meet the circumconic at $F$. A line through $F$ and parallel to $B'C'$ meets $AB$, $AC$ at $H$, $G$ (see Figure) then:*
> $$\frac{HG}{GF}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.$$

[image: Geometric arrangement described in the text]

Comment: I think 'amazing' doesn't belong in an MO question, at least not describing your own work.  I have edited it out, but of course you may revert if you find it in keeping with MO norms.

Comment: @LSpice thank you very much, I open to your suggestions

Comment: An equivalent statement is $HG^2=FG\cdot FH.$  This may be easier to prove.

Comment: @brainjam If $\frac{HG}{GF}=\varphi$ $\Rightarrow$ $HG^2=FG.FH$ but $HG^2=FG.FH$ no $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{HG}{GF}=\varphi$

Comment: This may be a consequence of [Poncelet's Porism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%27s_closure_theorem) for $n=3$.

Comment: Why? How can show that dear Mister @Kapil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider generalizing the last line to

> Let $I$ be a point on $B'C'$, and let $FI$ meet $AB$, $AC$ at $H$,
> $G$.
>
> Then the cross ratio of $H,F,G,I$ is the negative golden ratio: $$\frac{HG\cdot FI}{FG\cdot HI}=-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = -\phi$$

The original version is the limit of the general version as $I$ goes to infinity.

But the general version is projectively invariant, so we can prove it using coordinates where $A$ is at vertical infinity, the conic is $y=x^2$, and the tangent at $A$ is the line at infinity.

Then the first coordinates are simple:
\begin{align}
A &= \infty(0,1)\\
B &= (b,\ b^2)\\
C &= (c,\ c^2)\\
A' &= ((b+c)/2,\ bc)\\
B' &= \infty(1,2c)\\
C' &= \infty(1,2b)\\
D &= (c,\ (b-c)^2+c^2)\\
E &= (b,\ (b-c)^2+b^2)\\
F &= ((1-\phi)b+\phi c,\ ((1-\phi)b+\phi c)^2)\\
\end{align}
and we can stop computing coordinates there. The graphic below shows the case $b=-1$, $c=2$.

[image]

(There is also another solution for $F$, not mentioned in the original question, which leads to switching $\phi$ and $1-\phi$ in the above and the below.)

We want to evaluate the cross ratio $(HG\cdot FI)/(FG \cdot HI)$. Since $I$ is a point at infinity, the $FI$ and $HI$ terms will cancel. Then we can compute the directed quotient $HG/FG$ from the $x-$coordinates, which are $c$ and $b$ for $G$ and $H$. This gives us the desired result:
$$\frac{HG\cdot FI}{FG \cdot HI}=\frac{HG}{FG}=\frac{b-c}{(b-c)(1-\phi)}=-\phi$$